# make: [main.rel] Error 1 on SDCC -Eclipse IDE

Tags: eclipse, gcc, c, makefile

I'm trying to build a simple C program that blinks the LED on my MCS51 board but an error: make: *** [main.rel] Error 1 shows up. Can anyone advice me on how to fix this problem?

Here's my code for main:

```
#include  <8051.h>

void  delay()
{
  int  i,j;
  for (i = 0;i<=100;i++)
  for (j = 0;j<=100;j++);
}

void  main()
{
    while (1)
    {
        P1_0 =0;  // led glow
        delay();
        P1_0 = 1;   // led off
        delay();
    }

}
```

Comment: regarding: `void  main()`  This will cause the compiler to output a warning message about an invalid return value.  There are only two valid signatures for `main()`  They are: `int main( void )` and `int main( int argc, char *argv[] )`  Even if working with a bare board, the function: `start.s` is run first and is a safe place to return a `int` from `main()`

Comment: have you set the port 1, bit 0, to be an output via the port 1 data direction register?  have you set the internal pull up resister for port 1 bit 0  to be 'in use'?